# constant height for carousal with items having different height

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap Carousel having images of different heights. When the images change, the height of parent element is also changing, which disturbs the whole alignment of the page repeatedly.

Is there any way I can avoid that without setting the height in pixels, as that creates an issue when window sizes are small.

```
              <div>
                <Carousel style={displayImage}>
                  <Carousel.Item style={alignItem}>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1060/9112/products/Covid-19-01_8e003b8d-7115-41a2-b51c-1ef6d249d745_1024x1024.jpg?v=1583432489" />
                  </Carousel.Item>
                  <Carousel.Item style={alignItem}>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/8d/d1/bb8dd138ae9c8cbb9ad5caab6be7b7bd.png" />
                  </Carousel.Item>
                  <Carousel.Item style={alignItem}>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/43/29/c2/4329c2824fec2873b5e0569180e482cf.jpg" />
                  </Carousel.Item>
                  <Carousel.Item style={alignItem}>
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/08/27/14/19/mountains-55067__340.png" />
                  </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>
              </div>
```

style  is

```
var displayImage = {
      maxHeight: "500px",
      padding: "20px",
      overflow: "hidden",
      maxWidth: "300px",
      verticalAlign: "middle",
    };

    var alignItem = {
      verticalAlign: "middle",
    };
```

Comment: show us some code for it.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0):

As the CSS object-fit property is used to specify how an `<img>` or `<video>` should be resized to fit its container.

use this:

```
<div class="carousel-item ">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 fit" alt="...">
</div>
```

css:

```
 .fit{
      object-fit:cover;
 }
```

for your code add:

```
 var alignimage = {
      object-fit:"cover"
    };
```

and

```
<img class={alignimage}
src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/43/29/c2/4329c2824fec2873b5e0569180e482cf.jpg" />
```

**OR**

put inline styles:

```
 <img style={{object-fit: "cover"}} 
  src="blabblah.png" />
```

Comment: i am actually using react-bootstrap Carousel

Comment: you can actually see the webpage i am trying to set at https://fyi-vitc.web.app/#/event/qZjjmkkdSe89GpmJZq0r

Comment: also, the code you provided is not working.